# Is Gmail for Business an openID provider?

Tags: openid, gmail

Can accounts from apps for business([Gmail](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/gmail.html)) be used with openid?

Answer (score 3):

Yes they are. We use the Gmail from Google Apps for authentication for our internal home tools.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Google Apps accounts now work like full Google accounts and can do anything that normal Google accounts can do.